# Uppercase an array of strings with Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm trying to use [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#toUpper) to make a point free function to uppercase an array of strings, but I'm new to this and it isn't working out.

```
const list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
const fn = R.compose(R.toUpper, R.map)
console.log('result', fn(list))
```

gets me `Uncaught TypeError: function n(r){return 0===arguments.length||w(r)?n:t.apply(this,arguments)} does not have a method named "toUpperCase"`

I've also tried

```
const fn = R.compose(R.toUpper, R.map(list))
console.log('result', fn())
```

but get the same error.

How can I use Ramda to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to compose. `R.map` is curried so you could simply call it with single argument

```
const fn = R.map(R.toUpper)
```

[Demo](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?const%20list%20%3D%20%5B%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27%2C%20%27c%27%2C%20%27d%27%2C%20%27e%27%5D%0Aconst%20fn%20%3D%20R.map%28R.toUpper%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27result%27%2C%20fn%28list%29%29)

Comment: Awesome! When should `R.compose` be used?

Comment: When you need to call one function after another. Say `toUpper`  after `trim` [demo](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?const%20list%20%3D%20%5B%27%20a%20%27%2C%20%27%20b%27%20%2C%20%27%20c%20%27%2C%20%27%20d%20%27%2C%20%27%20e%20%27%5D%0Aconst%20fn%20%3D%20R.map%28%0A%20%20R.compose%28R.toUpper%2C%20R.trim%29%0A%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27result%27%2C%20fn%28list%29%29)